# propType for angular 2/4/7

Tags: angular

Is there any feature/library that works similar to react propType for angular? Something that lets you check if components prop supplied are of specific type and if a required property is provided.

Comment: You can use angular life cycle hooks. like `ngOnChanges`

Comment: Yes.is there some library which lets me easily do this.other wise I will have to write code to check if it of specific type, if required value is passed etc.